# Call startSerice() from anywhere in the app code

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to automatically insert some crafted code to any possible parts of the target app code. This crafted code includes a "context.startService()" to contact with a remote service from another app. How can I **automatically** get this context instance so that I can call startService() from anywhere within the app code?

Thanks a lot in advance. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Your activity or service is a context.  You need to pass it as a parameter to whatever other class wants to start the service.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. But the problem is I want to do this automatically and the location to start service is unpredictable. It is unfeasible to add context parameter to the arguments of ALL functions calls within an app.

Comment: Add it to your constructor, save it in a variable, and use it when you need it.

Comment: You still need to pass the context instance across several class constructors. For example Activity  -> class A -> class B -> class C, to get the context of Activity in class C, I need to modify all constructors of classes A,B,C. Any easier ways?

Comment: Other than changing your structure to be more android friendly, no.  In some cases I'd consider singleton or globals, but not for contexts-  too easy to cause massive memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to start a service from anywhere within your codebase without passing around context objects. The solution below is a way to do this but look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context) to get a better understanding of why this isn't always the best solution.

Create a class that extends from Application:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

  private static Application sInstance;

  public MyApplication() {
      sInstance = this;
  }

  public static Application getInstance() {
      return sInstance;
  }
}
```

This will give you access to your application's context so you can start a service from anywhere.

Now in some part of your code:

```
void foo() {
    MyApplication.getInstance().startService(new Intent(MY_SERVICE));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new method, that gets your context, and then calls your service with said context, then call that method instead.

shouldnt change your code much....

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How to get the context instance from a new method? Could you please provide any hints/code examples?? Thanks!